# weighting In Excel

Tags: excel

I have got two table in Excel:

First table looks like the following:

```
        A     B      C
Lysi    C4    D4     E4 
Maco    C5    D5     E5  
Mact    C6    D6     E6  
Mage    C7    D7     E7
```

and the second looks like

```
       Lysi     Maco Mact  Mage
1992    C13     D13  E13    F13
1993    C14     D14  E14    F14
1994    C15     D15  E15    F15
1995    C16     D16  E16    F16
1996    C17     D17  E17    F17
```

I would like to weight table 1 based on table 2 values, by multiplying the values of table 1 with values of tables 2 and suming up the resulting values. For example the resulting value of "A" in 1992 should be

```
(C4*C13)+(C5*D13)+(C6*E13)+(C7*F13)
```

final table should be like this below

```
       A    B   C
1992    *   *   *
1993    *   *   *
1994    *   *   *
1995    *   *   *
1996    *   *   *
```

or for example "C" in 1996 should be same as following formula

```
(E4*C17)+(E5*D17)+(E6*E17)+(E7*F17)
```

I would appriciate if you could help me with these questions:

1. Since both table are huge how can I mange this simple calculation for each row or column without any change. I mean this calculations for example `(E4*C17)+(E5*D17)+(E6*E17)+(E7*F17)`
2. What would you recommend to have my third table based on my explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Johnny's answer is good for a small table, but for larger tables, for a more extensible solution, you could use this formula

`=MMULT($C13:$F13+0,C$4:C$7+0)`

copied across and down for the whole table

or alternatively

`=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE($C13:$F13),C$4:C$7)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

both versions will allow blanks in the range (effectively treating those as zeroes), while the `SUMPRODUCT` version will allow text in the ranges (and ignore it)

Note: I'm assuming that the header/row label values are ordered the same in both tables